# GCC throws "pure virtual method called", but not when optimizations are on

Tags: c++

I have an abstract base class, ITracer, with pure virtual method logMessage.
ITracer also has a virtual destructor.
I have a derived class, NullTracer, which implements logMessage.

I have a class, TestClass, whose constructor optionally takes a const-ref ITracer. If no ITracer is provided, a NullTracer is instantiated.

TestClass has a method, test, which calls its ITracer's logMessage.
With GCC 11.2, "pure virtual method called" is thrown and "hello" is printed to stdout.
With GCC 11.2 and -O2, no exceptions are thrown and both "hello" and "test" are printed to stdout.

First, in the non-optimized case, what am I doing wrong? I don't understand which pure virtual functions I calling, NullTracer clearly has an implementation.

Second, in the optimized case, why is there no longer an exception and why does it execute the way I am expecting it to?

Edit: Can't believed I missed the dangling reference. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

class ITracer {
   public:
    virtual ~ITracer() = default;
    virtual void logMessage() const = 0;
};

class NullTracer : public ITracer {
   public:
    void logMessage() const override { std::cout << "test" << std::endl; };
};

class TestClass {
   public:
    TestClass(const ITracer& tracer = NullTracer()) : m_tracer(tracer) {}

    void test() {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
        m_tracer.logMessage();
    }

   private:
    const ITracer& m_tracer;
};

int main() {
        TestClass test;
        test.test();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/br6WxacKo

Comment: The curse of undefined behaviour is that, in some circumstances, it behaves in a way that you think is sane.   But in other circumstances it behaves differently.    Your observation (the program seems to run the way you expect when optimisation is enabled, and runs differently when optimisation is disabled) is completely consistent with that.   Practically, a number of modern compilers deal with some forms of undefined behaviour by simply emitting code that seems (according to testing) to not have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `TestClass` constructor creates a temporary `NullTracer` object, the const-reference parameter `tracer` ensures that the object lives only for the lifetime of the constructor call.  When the constructor exits, the temporary object gets destroyed.

Even though the `m_tracer` class member is also a const-reference, it DOES NOT  extend the lifetime of the temporary `NullTracer` object any further. And so, you end up calling `logMessage()` via a **dangling reference** to an invalid object, which is *undefined behavior*.

You need to explicitly extend the lifetime of the `NullTracer` object, either by:

- copying the object by value into another class member, and then set `m_tracer` to refer to that member instead
- set `m_tracer` to refer to a static `NullTracer` object
- use pointers instead of references, and then create the `NullTracer` object dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the same thing wrong in all cases, namely having a dangling reference and assuming the prior object still is there.
It isn't, the call is undefined behavior, and whatever happens will happen.

Specifically, you are binding the member `m_tracer` to the default-argument `NullTracer()` which creates a temporary object. At the end of the ctor-call, that temporary is destroyed.

What you should do is have some `NullTracer` with static lifetime somewhere, and refer to that.

```
NullTracer defaultNullTracer;

class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(const ITracer& tracer = defaultNullTracer) : m_tracer(tracer) {}
    TestClass(const ITracer&&) = delete; // disabled for safety
```